# Postgres stating error when performing a subquery error at or near select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know this question will be easy for most people. But I really expected that this would work.
Why doesn't this query work?

```
select name, price,  select num from ( select 1 as num) as value 
from products;
```

I've got this:

error at or near select

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with single `SELECT` statement :

```
select name, price, 1 as value 
from products;
```

Single outer `SELECT` statement should contains only columns/expressions, if it has other `SELECT` statements then it should be in `subquery` form.

something like that :

```
select t.col1, t.col2 t.col3,
       (select t1.col from table t1 where . . . ) as col_name
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

answer depends on what you want to do exactly.

remember that `select 1 from table`  is a correct sql query, which returns "the first column" from the table

it explains why you have a syntax error in your query. the `from table` is missing in your `(select 1 as num)`

so let's confirm what your want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Why does this fail?

```
select name, price,  select num from ( select 1 as num) as value 
from products;
```

`select` is a SQL keyword that indicates either a new query or a subquery.  When used with a subquery, it must be preceded by its own parentheses.  Hence, you get a syntax error.

If you add the parentheses:

```
select name, price,  (select num from ( select 1 as num)) as value 
from products;
```

You will get a *different* error, because the nested subquery is missing a table alias.

In the end, you can fix this to what you presumably intend:

select p.name, p.price, 
       (select num from (select 1 as num) x) as value 
from products p;